# How to remove deployed smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, ram

I want to sorta "undeploy" smart contract as it was not deployed ever.
If it is possible, I hope it will cleanup account's RAM.
And I'm not talking about [freezing](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/can-we-freeze-our-deployed-smart-contract) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cleos set contract --help`

Specifically you want `--clear`

You are required to manually clear the contract tables if you no longer want the data. Clearing a contract with existing data will not remove the RAM used to store the data in tables.

Comment: Basically  I look at [this](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-set-contract) docs thought I know it can be old ), I should make a habit to look more at --help. Thank you.